# no matching function for call to Class::Method

Tags: c++, class, scope, declaration, function-declaration

When trying to implement a Priority Search Tree, i get this error when trying to build the tree

> error: no matching function for call to 'ArbolP::crearArbol(ArrRazon*&, int, int&)

> note: candidate: 'void ArbolP::crearArbol(ArbolP::ArrRazon*, int, int)'

Also, I could use some help with PST

.h ArbolP file

```
#define ARBOLP_H
#include <Empresa.h>


class ArbolP
{

    public:
        struct ArrRazon {
            int posicion;
            int empleados;
        };

         struct Arbol{
            ArrRazon razon;
            float mediana;
            Arbol *izq;
            Arbol *der;
        };

        ArbolP();
        virtual ~ArbolP();
        ArbolP::Arbol * crearNodo(ArrRazon razon, Arbol * izq, Arbol * der, float mediana);
        int posicionEnRanking(ArrRazon *arreglo, int inicio, int tamanio_arreglo);
        float calcular_mediana(ArrRazon *arreglo, int tamanio_arreglo, int pos);
        void crearArbol(ArrRazon *arreglo, int inicio, int tamanio_arreglo);

    private:

        Arbol *raiz;


};

#endif // ARBOLP_H
```

ArbolP.cpp file

```
ArbolP::ArbolP()
{
    //ctor
    raiz = NULL;
}

void moverInicio(ArbolP::ArrRazon *arreglo, int inicio, int menorP){
    ArbolP::ArrRazon aux = arreglo[inicio];
    arreglo[inicio] = arreglo[menorP];
    arreglo[menorP] = aux;
}

int posicionMediana(ArbolP::ArrRazon *arreglo, int inicio, int fin, float mediana){
    while (inicio<fin){
        if (arreglo[inicio].empleados >= mediana)
            return inicio;
        inicio++;
    }
    return -1;
}

ArbolP::Arbol * crearNodo(ArbolP::ArrRazon razon, ArbolP::Arbol * izq, ArbolP::Arbol * der, float mediana){
    ArbolP::Arbol * nodo = new ArbolP::Arbol;
    nodo->razon = razon;
    nodo->izq = izq;
    nodo->der = der;
    nodo->mediana = mediana;
    return nodo;
}

void crearDuplicado(ArbolP::ArrRazon *arreglo, ArbolP::ArrRazon *aux, int tamanio_arreglo){
    for (int i=0; i<tamanio_arreglo; i++)
        aux[i] = arreglo[i];
}

ArbolP::Arbol *construirArbol(ArbolP::ArrRazon  *arreglo, int inicio, int fin){
    if (inicio > fin)
        return NULL;

    int empresaMenorP = posicionEnRanking(arreglo, inicio, fin);

    moverInicio(arreglo, inicio, empresaMenorP);

    float mediana = -1;

    int nuevoInicio = inicio+1;

    ArbolP::Arbol * ramaIzq = NULL;
    ArbolP::Arbol * ramaDer = NULL;

    if (inicio < fin){
        mediana = calcular_mediana(arreglo, fin, nuevoInicio);

        int posicionMIzq = posicionMediana(arreglo, nuevoInicio, fin, mediana);

        if (posicionMIzq != -1){
            ramaIzq = construirArbol(arreglo, nuevoInicio, posicionMIzq);
            ramaDer = construirArbol(arreglo, posicionMIzq+1, fin);
        } else{
            ramaDer = construirArbol(arreglo, nuevoInicio, fin);
        }
    }

    ArbolP::Arbol *nuevoNodo = crearNodo(arreglo[inicio], ramaIzq, ramaDer, mediana);

    return nuevoNodo;

}

void ArbolP::crearArbol(ArrRazon *arreglo, int inicio, int tamanio_arreglo)
{
    ArrRazon arregloE[tamanio_arreglo];
    crearDuplicado(arreglo, arregloE, tamanio_arreglo);

    mergeSortE(arregloE, inicio, tamanio_arreglo);

    raiz = construirArbol(arregloE, inicio, tamanio_arreglo-1);
}

ArbolP::~ArbolP()
{
    //dtor
}
```

main file

```
struct ArrRazon {
    int posicion;
    int empleados;
    string razonsocial;
};
struct ArregloServicio {
            int posicion;
            int empleados;
        };

int main()
{   int l=0;
    int tamanio_arreglo;//El entero tamanio_arreglo se usa como condicion de corte en los servicios
    Empresa* arreglo = procesar_archivo_entrada("ranking_empresas.csv",tamanio_arreglo);
    ArrRazon* ArregloRazon = new ArrRazon[tamanio_arreglo];
    ArbolP nuevo;
    nuevo.crearArbol(ArregloRazon, 0, tamanio_arreglo);
    delete [] arreglo;
    delete [] ArregloRazon;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `ArrRazon` in the main file and `ArbolP::ArrRazon` in the class ArbolP are different types.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to extend the class `ArbolP::ArrRazon` with a string member. You should inherit that class, not rewrite it in the main file.

```
struct ArrRazon : public ArbolP::ArrRazon {
    string razonsocial;
};
```

`ArrRazon arregloE[tamanio_arreglo];` is not a standard C++ support of VLA.

`crearDuplicado` will not work with a such design. It can't deal with child classes of `ArbolP::ArrRazon`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by making a class ArrRazon

Answer (score 0):

In this member function declaration

```
void crearArbol(ArrRazon *arreglo, int inicio, int tamanio_arreglo);
```

the type specifier ArrRazon refers to the member of the class ArbolP.

```
class ArbolP
{

    public:
        struct ArrRazon {
            int posicion;
            int empleados;
        };
        //...
        void crearArbol(ArrRazon *arreglo, int inicio, int tamanio_arreglo);
};
```

However in the module with main you declared a structure with the same name in the global namespace and you are trying to call the member function with an object of this new type specifier

```
struct ArrRazon {
    int posicion;
    int empleados;
    string razonsocial;
};
struct ArregloServicio {
            int posicion;
            int empleados;
        };

int main()
{   int l=0;
    int tamanio_arreglo;//El entero tamanio_arreglo se usa como condicion de corte en los servicios
    Empresa* arreglo = procesar_archivo_entrada("ranking_empresas.csv",tamanio_arreglo);
    ArrRazon* ArregloRazon = new ArrRazon[tamanio_arreglo];
    ArbolP nuevo;
    nuevo.crearArbol(ArregloRazon, 0, tamanio_arreglo);
    //...
```

So the compiler issues an error because `ArbolP::ArrRazon` and `::ArrRazon` are two different types.

Comment: I fixed it by making ArrRazon a separate class, instead of porting the struct everywhere i needed it.